# Need help getting into Facebook account after password reset

Tags: facebook

Just the other day I noticed my ex had been in my account & I forgot to change my password & a couple days later I tried to sign back in & it said wrong password so I clicked on "I forgot my password" & I reset it. Well when I tried to sign in afterwards it said to try again in 23 hours.

I waited until the following night & tried again & now it says

> this username is already in use. Please try again using a different username or email,"

But thats the same email I have always used to sign into my facebook.

What do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you need to contact Facebook support and report the account as "hacked".

Click on **My account is hacked** on [this page](https://www.facebook.com/help/131719720300233/).  This will help you know what options Facebook makes available in your situation, as this will probably require several verifications and may need manual intervention.